# how to make a transparent navbar that's not fixed-top?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, web, responsive-design

I want to make transparent navbar in Bootstrap that's not fixed-top but I'm not able to do it with Bootstrap. Should I make it with pure CSS or I can find another option with Bootstrap ?

Answer (score 0):

Try the snippet below

```css
.navbar-default{
  background-color: transparent !important;
}
```

```html
   <meta charset="utf-8">
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
   <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
   <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<body style="background-color: #5cb85c;">
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
     <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar">
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>                        
       </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="/"><i class="fa fa-code"></i> TC</a>
    </div>
   <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <li class="active"><a href="/" class="home">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="templates" class="templates">Page 2</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
 </div>
</nav>
</body>
```

Comment: You can additionaly change the style for the toggle menu (it apperas, because the frame is small) and the style for the nav items. Remember! This always works:
`selector {
    property-name: property-value !important;
}`

Answer (score 0):

`<nav class="navbar navbar-default">`

Just remove the `navbar-fixed-top` class

Then use `CSS` to make it transparent

`.navbar-default {background-color:transparent}`